# Creating a 1D heat map using the data which is unequally spaced

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, heatmap, linegraph

I have a set of X,Y data points that are easy to plot as a line graph but that I would like to represent as a heatmap.

I looked through the examples in Matplotlib and they all seem to already start with heatmap cell values to generate the image. The data in these examples are equally spaced.

The mismatch is reflected in the attach image  where zones with higher frequency of x, y would not be "warmer".

[image]

Is there a method that converts a bunch of x, y, all different, to a heatmap (with a linear distribution like the line graph)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share with us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What defines the colour of  heatmap? As the density of x is equally spaced, what makes it red and blue and dark blue?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't want frequency of x to have an effect, just the average value of y within each "bin".  I suggest binning your data as though planning to use a histogram, and use the binned data to generate the heatmap instead.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to convert your vector into a matrix in order to call the `image` function. Then you can combine these two plots as you like; e.g.

```
set.seed(12346)
ts.sim <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.7), n = 200)
ts.plot(ts.sim)

m <- list(x = time(ts.sim), y = 1, z = as.matrix(ts.sim))

op <- par(mfrow = c(2,1))
image(m, yaxt = "n")
plot(z ~ x, m, xaxs = "i", t = "l")
par(op)
```

[image]